# How to crossmatch data of a column with multiple column and take action if it matched?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

Here I have two sheets in google spreadsheet.
[Please check the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL2rV.jpg)

I would like to automatically search all the single data of column A of Sheet 2 in Column A and C of Sheet 1 and if it matched it would make the checkboxes ticked on column B and D of sheet 1 and if its not matched it would leave it as it was. I have attached that screenshot which is the result I expect. Is there any functions or script to do this?

I'm not familiar with such staffs. A help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you do not need to write a script for this - an array formula can do it all

to the formula start working - you need to clear out everything from the range `B1:B7` . then paste the formula `=ArrayFormula(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A7,Sheet2!$A:$A,1,false),)=A1:A7)` into cell `B1`, then select range `B1:B7` and paste checkboxes through the menu `Insert` - `Checkbox`

[image]

the formula for the range `D1:D7` is inserted in the same way

`=ArrayFormula(IFNA(VLOOKUP(C1:C7,Sheet2!$A:$A,1,false),)=C1:C7)`

[image]

after some thought, came to the conclusion that the formulas could be much simpler
`=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A:$A,A1:A7)>0)` for cell `B1`
`=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A:$A,C1:C7)>0)` for cell `D1`

Comment: Thank you so much. It works fine and it helps me a lot in my office.